# Ruby on Rails Model エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsを用いてWebアプリケーションの開発を行なっています。
ただいま、http://localhost:3000/country_roads でアクセスすると

> Unable to autoload constant Country_Road, expected /Users/account/road_app/app/models/country_road.rb to define it

というエラーメッセージが出ます。

stack over flow等で検索するとファイル名のミスが原因となる。と記載があります。
しかしながら、ファイル名のミスはなさそうなので、どうミスがあるのか知りたいです。

コマンド実行は次のように行いました。

> rails g model country_roads name:string pass:string
>    rails g controller country_roads

コマンドを実行し、Railsでモデルとコントローラを作成しました。データベースは

> rails db:create
>   rails db:migrate

を行いデータベース・coutry_roadsテーブルの作成をしました。

country_roads_controller.rbでは

> def index
>           @country_roads = CountryRoad.all
>       end

と宣言しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unable to autoload constant`の原因は、誤ってソース内に,`CountryRoad`と書くべきところに、`Country_Road`と記載しているからだと思います。

ソース内に、`Country_Road`の記載がないか確認してください。

以下などが参考になるかもしれません。

[RailsでLoadError: Unable to autoload constantの原因](http://okerra.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/03/082902)

Comment: (前回に引き続き、)早速のお返事ありがとうございます。
全てのファイルを見直して `Coutry_Road` の記載を全て修正したら
正しく認識されるようになりました